# Python Order of Operations

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

I'm learning to code and I'm having a very tough time understanding how the code below works. The piece of code is a function that provides a solution to a problem, which is given a number of heads and legs, how many pigs and chickens do you have. The comments show where I'm hitting a roadblock can anyone help shed some light on these roadblocks for me? The code works I just don't know how/why. Thanks so much!

```
def solve(numLegs, numHeads):
    for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):
        numPigs = numHeads - numChicks #So this says numPigs is equal to (5,4,3,2,1,0)
        totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks #I don't understand how the math is caluclated here.
        #I'd assume this is equal to 4*(5,4,3,2,1,0) + 2*(0,1,2,3,4,5). But how does that calculate?


        if totLegs == numLegs: #finally here, if totLegs is equal to a list, and so are numPigs, and numChicks
                                #how do you get one value for each??

            print (numPigs, numChicks)
    return (None, None)


solve(14,5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have p pigs and c chicken there are p+c heads in total since each animal has one head and 4*p+2*c legs since each pig has 4 legs and each chick has 2 legs.

This leads to two constraints

1. heads = p + c
2. legs = 4*p + 2*c

In the code:

```
for numChicks in range(0, numHeads + 1):
```

Loops through possible values for the number of chicken (c). So numChicks takes the values 1, 2, 3, etc. in sequence.

```
numPigs = numHeads - numChicks
```

Calculates based on the first constraint.

```
totLegs = 4*numPigs + 2*numChicks
```

Checks if the second constraint holds

```
if totLegs == numLegs:
```

Checks if the value found is the expected

Comment: Thank You. Makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

> So this says numPigs is equal to (5,4,3,2,1,0)

No, it doesn't say that. The body of the `for` loop is executed `numHeads+1` times. On the first execution, `numPigs` is 5. On the second execution, it is 4, and so on.

> if totLegs is equal to a list

It isn't, it's a number.

Comment: Yeah, "loops" are called that because they run multiple times.

Comment: Thank You. I get it now! I was totally overlooking the loop part!